# Is there any way to find out whether the browser UI thread is busy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, settimeout

Looking for an event or another way to find out whether UI is actually done processing items in queue.

My specific case while using angular, and doing some(big) UI update, UI gets stuck for some time. $scope.$apply() is the function which happens during this time(got from devtools profile).

I have tried setTimeout($timeout) with 0 time. This gets called once all functions in queue are executed. But UI hangs for more time after setTimeout is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Umm..

I don't know whether this would actually help you or not.

But there is something like [`requestIdleCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback), though it also enqueue a task in queue .. but this task would execute only when browser's thread is free and you can also force it to execute after certain amout of time.